# How do I stack feature class annotation?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, editing, annotation

I have map annotation that is stored in a database (as a feature class), but that is not linked to the features. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to edit it so that I can take a label of say 3 words and stack it so that one word is on top of the other, like so:

From: 
How To Stack

To: 
How 
To 
Stack

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many annotations are there that you need to stack this way? This can be easily done manually while editing but would be a tedious process - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you have the Maplex extension?

Comment: There are quite a few. I do have Maplex and have been using it, but I think I need to decrease the # of characters on a line so that more of these labels are going to stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation classes are very hard indeed to edit.
In fact can only be overridden not edited.

On top of that there are no tools I know of in the annotation to stack labels.  I believe the only option you would have is to start with a regular feature class, label it with maplex custom (stack options) properties, and then create an annotation class from that.

With maplex you can set specific characters to cause stacking.
For instance if you hav commas or spaces .  ?

Comment: I believe you are correct on this. The only other way is to create graphical text and convert it to annotation using the annotation construction tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000000w000000

Comment: Yea, this seems to be the same conclusion I am coming to...